# Customize WordPress>Error Page

Tags: theme-development, errors

Is there a way to customize the WordPress>error page template so that the user isn't shown just a blank screen with text?

I'm not talking about 404, but when WordPress displays an error.

I'd like to style this page to match my theme.

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of error you're talking about?

Comment: If you look at the link that Michael put below, that's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably talking about theming `wp_die()`, which is the function that produces those grey  error pages with a white box of text in them.

**For a plugin solution**, you could try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mudslide-error-pages/), which says it does what you want. Not sure about version support though--it says it only works up to 3.1.4.

**For a programatic solution**, you'll want to hook into the filter "wp_die_handler". So you can do:

```
add_filter('wp_die_handler', 'my_die_handler');
```

As far as code for the `my_die_handler` function, you could start by looking at the default die handler -- the function is called `_default_wp_die_handler`, and it starts on line 2796 of the core file [`/wp-includes/functions.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7ec3bfe1ce7271e94409a906bba22dbfe5a95078/wp-includes/functions.php#L2796). You can copy the whole function to your plugin file (or your theme's functions file), rename it `my_die_handler`, and customize it from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a custom die handler:

```
add_filter('wp_die_handler', 'get_custom_die_handler' );

function get_custom_die_handler() {
    return 'custom_die_handler';
}

function custom_die_handler( $message, $title="", $args = array() ) {
    echo '<html><body>';
    echo '<h1>Error:</h1>';
    echo $message; /* No escaping, to match the default behaviour */
    echo '</body></html>';
    die();
}
```

Notice that you need to create two functions: both your custom die handler, and a function that returns the name of your custom die handler.

You can look at `_default_wp_die_handler` for inspiration on what to put in the contents of `custom_die_handler`, you can find it in [`wp-includes/functions.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php). Don't forget to call `die();`.

#### Reference:

- http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/custom-wordpress-comment-error-page/